# Override operator Int RangeTo not working

Tags: kotlin

I write the operator

```
private fun method() {
    operator fun Float.rangeTo(other: Int) {
        (this.toInt()..other).forEach { print(it) }
    }
    0f..4
}
```

This works well i.e. printing `01234`

But when I replace the `float` with `Int`, it no longer works i.e. not printing `01234`

```
private fun method() {
    operator fun Int.rangeTo(other: Int) {
        (this..other).forEach { print(it) }
    }
    0..4
}
```

What did I miss? How could I get it work?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at this code in IntelliJ, you'll get your answer in the form of a warning on your `rangeTo` function:

> Extension is shadowed by a member: public final operator fun rangeTo(other: Int): IntRange

Extensions can't override methods that a type already has, and since `Int` has a non-extension `rangeTo(Int)` method, the `0..4` syntax will always call that method. If you think about it, you're actually making use of this fact when you write down `this..other`, as that's a call to the built-in `rangeTo` operator, and not a recursive call to your own extension function.

The reason why it worked with a `Float` is that it doesn't have a member `rangeTo(Int)` method of its own.

Answer (score 1):

`rangeTo` is already a member of `Int` and it shadows as you can see in Intellij IDEA the operator you create. This is by design.